# How does one cache an entire functional component in React?

Tags: reactjs, memoization

I've built a tabs component. Each tab, when clicked, changes the contents of the "main screen". Assume a tab had some back-end call to retrieve data it needs to render, then it makes no sense to have it re-run these calls every time the user clicks another tab and comes back to it. I want to retrieve what was rendered before and display it.

I looked into `memo`, the big warning says to "not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.", nor does it work. Every time I wrap my component in a memo, the test:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Rendered');
}, [])
```

Still runs, telling me that the component re-rendered. Then I thought about memoizing the return itself, so, like:

```
export const MyComponent = (context) => {
  const content = useMemo(() => {
    return <></>
  }, [context]);

  return content;
};
```

But quickly realized that by the time I reach this `useMemo`, I'm already in the re-rendering cycle, because there's no way for React to know that `MyComponent`'s `useMemo` existed in the past, so, again, it re-renders the whole thing. This, in turn made me think that the memoization needs to be done at the level where `MyComponent` is being rendered, not inside of it but I don't know how to do it.

How can I skip re-renders if my props haven't changed?

Read all the articles, tried all the things but to no avail.

Concisely, here is my component and my latest approach:

```
export const MyComponent = memo(({ context, className = '', ...props }) => {
  ..
  ..
});
```

The interesting bit here is `context`. This should almost never change. Its structure is a deeply nested object, however, when I play with `memo`'s second argument, its diff function, what ends up happening if I put a `console.log` in there, as follows:

```
const MyComponent = ({ context, className = '', ...props }) => {
};

const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  console.log('Did equality check.');
};

export default memo(MyComponent, areEqual);
```

I will only see "Did equality check." once. No matter what I do, I can't seem to get a memoized component out of `memo`. This is how `MyComponent`'s parent looks like:

```js
const Parent = ({}) => {

  const context = useSelector(); //context comes from the store.
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(false);
  const [content, setContent] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    switch (selectedTab) {
      case 'components':
        setContent(<MyComponent context={context} />);
        break;
    }
  }, [selectedTab, context]);

  return(<>{content}</>);
};
```

Comment: `memo()` is the established tool for caching components. If it's not working for you, please show us your attempt with enough detail to understand your situation.

Comment: @JLRishe It's just a dead-simple `memo()` implementation as per the docs. I wonder if my testing is flawed. As I explained, I have a `useEffect` running on each render that `console.log` something. In theory, if the component was to be cached, that wouldn't happen because it wouldn't re-render, but it does.

Comment: @Luka That's not the point of the question, while I could use it to cache requests, it was obvious that this "make a request" thing was just meant to exemplify one case in which I'd want to cache an entire component.

Comment: Clearly it's not dead-simple if it's not working. `React.memo` will cache your component as long as the _props_ remain the same. In your case, are the props staying the same, or changing? As I already pointed out, there's not much we can tell you if you won't show us your actual code. If you want to check whether the component is rendering, put the `console.log` directly in the component function. It's very possible that your extraneous `useEffect` is helping to foul things up.

Comment: @JLRishe I updated my question after trying on my own for a bit longer but to no avail. Honestly, the update is just the basic implementation of `memo`. Something that is probably worth mentioning is that `MyComponent` gets rendered based on a state change (if key === something -> render `MyComponent`), this state changes quite often.

Comment: So you're passing your entire store into the component as a prop (or are you leaving out some details on that `useSelector` line)? If it's the former, that's going to cause a re-render every time the store changes.

Answer (score 0):

@daniel-james I think the problem here is we are un-mounting the whole component when we are switching tabs. Instead try memoizing the component in the parent itself. That way your component is memoized only once.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please modify your answer and provide sample source code/config changes that the user should do to solve the problem.